# How to Update or Insert a record using SQL Merge

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a windows forms application that needs to edit an existing record if it already exists and create it if it does not. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. My application reads data from various tables which includes an ID field for the output table if a record already exists.

The ID field is blank if a new record is being created. The ID field is the primary key and an Identity (auto increment) field for the destination table.

I have created a stored procedure using MERGE that I hope will create a new record or update the existing one.  The update part is working but I can't figure out what to do with the ID field when creating.

When doing an update I pass in an ID Parameter and the existing record is located.  Obviously if it is a new record I won't have an ID yet but I can't then leave that Parameter out or I get an unassigned variable error as you would expect.

Here is my stored procedure.  Am I just barking up the wrong tree here
somewhere?

Should I just create two stored procedures and call Update if I have and ID and Call Create if I don't have and ID?

Thanks for any assistance.

```
USE [Insurance]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateModifyValuation]

-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ValuationID int,
@OwnersCorporationID int,
@ValDate    datetime,
@ValuerID   int,
@Amount     money,
@Printed    bit,
@Approved   bit,
@Notes      varchar(max),
@MultiplierValue money,
@MultiplierClass    char(10),
@Adjustment money,
    @SubmittedDate datetime

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here

Merge Valuation as Target
USING (Select   
            @ValuationID,
            @OwnersCorporationID, 
            @ValDate,   
            @ValuerID, 
            @Amount, 
            @Printed, 
            @Approved, 
            @Notes, 
            @MultiplierValue, 
            @MultiplierClass, 
            @Adjustment,
            @SubmittedDate
        )
        As Source(
            ValuationID,
            OwnersCorporationID, 
            ValDate,    
            ValuerID, 
            Amount, 
            Printed, 
            Approved, 
            Notes, 
            MultiplierValue, 
            MultiplierClass, 
            Adjustment,
            SubmittedDate
        )

ON Source.ValuationID = Target.ValuationID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
    Target.OwnersCorporationID = Source.OwnersCorporationID,
    Target.ValDate = Source.ValDate,
    Target.ValuerID = Source.ValuerID,
    Target.Amount = Source.Amount,
    Target.Printed = Source.Printed,
    Target.Approved = Source.Approved,
    Target.Notes = Source.Notes,
    Target.MultiplierValue = Source.MultiplierValue,
    Target.MultiplierClass = Source.MultiplierClass,
    Target.Adjustment = Source.Adjustment,
    Target.SubmittedDate = Source.SubmittedDate

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
INSERT (
            OwnerscorporationID,
            ValDate,
            ValuerID,
            Amount,
            Printed,
            Approved,
            Notes,
            MultiplierValue,
            MultiplierClass,
            Adjustment,
            SubmittedDate
        )
VALUES  (
            Source.OwnersCorporationID,
            Source.ValDate,
            Source.ValuerID,
            Source.Amount,
            Source.Printed,
            Source.Approved,
            Source.Notes,
            Source.MultiplierValue,
            Source.MultiplierClass,
            Source.Adjustment,
            Source.SubmittedDate    
        );

END
```

Comment: Your merge statement seems fine to me, but I don't understand the problem - do you get any errors when inserting a new record?

Comment: I could be misunderstanding your question, as the MERGE looks fine, but couldn't you just make the `@ValuationId` parameter nullable? (E.g `@ValuationID int = NULL`)

Comment: If, in my C# program I try and assign null to ValuationID, which is an int I get a compile time error "Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nulable value type".  So I need to call my SP once with a ValuationID and Once Witthout and I don't see how to do it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I cheated but it's only one line so how bad can it be :)

In My SQL I added this line before the "SET NOCOUNT ON;"

(Funny if I put it after SET NOCOUNT ON I get a syntax error)

```
if (@ValuationID = 0) set @ValuationID = null
```

Then in my C# code I set the ID to 0 for a new record and it seems to work after a couple of tests.  There may be a better way to do this but like most things in life you stop looking once it works.
Thanks again to those who commented.

David